# The image isn't displayed on the page (ImageField)

Tags: python, django, django-models

MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL aren't defined in settings.py

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from img.models import Profile

def index(request):
    p = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=1)
    return render(request, '1.html', {'p': p})
```

I don't think that is important, but my urls.py

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
 from img import views

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
 )
```

And my template **(img src="avatars/00.jpeg in HTML)**

```
<img src="{{ p.avatar.url }}" />
```

My project tree
[image: My project tree]

What it is necessary to correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure static files

Have a look here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/